# Naming an Invention

Tags: riddle

Blake, Ruby and Yvette are all creative inventors and live on the same cul-de-sac. Blake and Ruby have a daughter named Vivian. Blake has another daughter, Grace, with Yvette.

Ruby and Yvette patented a medical device they called Ollie.
Blake also teamed up with Grace to invent a candy-making machine.

Which one of the following 5 names did Blake and Grace **NOT** consider when naming their invention, and why?

> 1. Ambrosial Treats
> 2. Bunch O'Candy
> 3. Candilicious
> 4. Real Tasty
> 5. Turbo Sweets

Comment: It would help me if I could have some constructive criticism on these downvotes, so I can do better next time.

Comment: "That's a 'fresher'. I'm going on break."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along the same lines as [leoll2's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10977/5373), I looked at different names for

> a colour between blue and green.

Possibilities include

> cyan, turquoise, aqua, and blue-green, which begin with the letters C, T, A, and B.

So the answer is

> 4. Real Tasty.

Comment: Robin's Egg Blue? :-)

Comment: @Joffan Ah but is that between blue and green? :-)

Comment: I'd say it's *exactly* the kind of colour that men and women tend to disagree about whether it's green or blue. I love that range of colours, myself.

Answer (score 8):

> Let's consider the initials of their names, which are also the initials of primary and secondary colors.

Ruby and Blake

> RED+BLUE=VIOLET

Blake and Yvette

> BLUE+YELLOW=GREEN

Ruby and Yvette

> RED+YELLOW=ORANGE

Blake and Grace

> BLUE+GREEN=TURQUOISE(?)

Finally:

> Their options to choose the name of the final color could be Turbo Sweets (Turquoise/Teal), Ambrosial Treats (Aqua), Candilicious (Cyan), Bunch O'Candy (Brandeir). It's missing **Real Tasty**.

Comment: The trouble with posting partial answers is that someone else may steal your idea to finish it off... ;-) I've deliberately not re-explained your idea, so that people need to go to your answer to understand the solution. Yours deserves more credit than mine!

Comment: +1 I wanted to give it to you leoll2, but it just wasn't complete. rand doesn't need any more rep points! haha

Comment: Eheh thanks for it! Also, congrats for solving it!

Comment: PS: of course I had to google the names of the shades of blue, I'm not a girl ahah!